# PHP Form coding with no response

Tags: php

I have used php code inside my page but its not working in localhost showing the undefined variable in the textboxes and selectboxes which I have given like this:

```
$propertyid = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9-]", "", $_POST['propertyid']); 
$propertyname = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_POST['propertyname']); 
$propertytype = ereg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['propertytype']); 
$propertydealtype = ereg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['propertydealtype']);
$propertystreet = ereg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['propertystreet']);




<td width="249" align="left" valign="middle">PropertyID:</td>
  <td width="739"><input name="propertyid" type="text" value="<?php echo "$propertyid"; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
  <td width="249" align="left" valign="middle">PropertyName:</td>
  <td width="739"><input name="propertyname" type="text" value="<?php echo "$propertyname"; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="left" valign="middle">Property Type:</td>
  <td><select name="propertytype">
  <option value="<?php echo "$propertytype"; ?>"><?php echo "$propertytype"; ?></option>
  <option value="Appartment/Fla">Appartment/Flat</option>
  <option value="Farm House">Farm House</option>
  <option value="Guest House">Guest House</option>
  <option value="Lord">Lord</option>
  <option value="Hostel">Hostel</option>
  </select></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
  <td align="left" valign="middle">Deal Type:</td>
  <td><select name="propertydealtype">
    <option value="<?php echo "$propertydealtype"; ?>"><?php echo "$propertydealtype"; ?></option>
    <option value="For Sale">For Sale</option>
    <option value="For Rent">For Rent</option>
    <option value="For Lease">For Lease</option>
    <option value="Ejara">Ejara</option>
    <option value="Sar Qulfi">Sar Qulfi</option>
  </select></td>

<tr>
  <td align="left" valign="middle">Property Streeet:</td>
  <td><input name="propertystreet" type="text" value="<?php echo "$propertystreet"; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
```

inside of each box whenever i am executing in localhost receiving errors inside boxes.

Comment: ereg_replace is deprecated. Use preg_replace instead.

Comment: You are assuming `$_POST` is set without actually checking. On initial page load, before the form is posted, you are going to get notices because none of those keys in $_POST exist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how really ereg_replace works, but first of all it's deprecated, and second - I think you cannot have spaces between the expressions => "[^A-Z a-z0-9]" should be "[^A-Za-z0-9]"

Comment: Thanks. Then let's go ahead. I don't know what's recieved through POST to test, but I think here also could be a problem -> value="<?php echo "$propertystreet"; ?>" />  the quotes should be escaped

Answer (score 0):

Your `input` tags should be inside a `form` tag... where is your `form` tag?
`$_POST` retrieve your input data from a `form`

Comment: His `tr` tags should be inside `table` tags too. Just because he didn't paste them in the example doesn't mean they aren't there. The form probably surrounds the table.

Answer (score 0):

during echo, variables don't need to be in quotes. so it's better like this:

```
    <?php echo $propertytype; ?>.
```

undefined variable error means that probably the $_POST are not defined. But in this case you should get errors there as well.

From php page about function ereg_replace : This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.